# Iteration issue

Tags: python, iteration

I am working on a bike-sharing program in Paris called Velib. The R_0 list that is displayed below contains all the information of all the bike stations in paris and I am trying to quantify the changes of value of bikes in each bike station during a certain amount of time to see which bike station has the most users and so on.

lR0 is the length of R_0. What i did was make 2 lists, and iterate. The 1st list Lt0 contains the value of bikes a a time t and the 2nd list Lt1 at a time t+T and I create a new list I_0 to which is added the abs(variation) of bikes during a time T. So at the end I will have a list with an approximate variation of the bikes during the whole period ( The exact variation would be given if T -> 0 ).

Unfortunately my list I_0 has been [0,0,...,0,0] for all iterations, even though i refresh the number of bikes at each station at each iteration. Is there a problem with the refreshing of R_0 ? does python actually re use the old j son list sent back from the site every time ? Is there an issue with the order of my code ?

```
I_0=np.zeros(lR0)

Lt1=np.zeros(lR0)

for k in range (0,lR0-1):
    Lt1[k]=R_0[k]['available_bikes']

Lt0=Lt1    

c=0

while c<288:

    c=c+1
    R_0_json = requests.get('https://api.jcdecaux.com/vls/v1/stations?contract=Paris&apiKey=an apikey')
    R_0=R_0_json.json()
    lR0=len(R_0)

    for k in range (0,lR0-1):
        I_0[k]=I_0[k]+abs(Lt1[k]-Lt0[k])
        Lt0[k]=Lt1[k]
        Lt1[k]=R_0[k]['available_bikes']

        time.sleep (150)


print(I_0)
```

R_0 looks like this:

```
[{'last_update': 1497175405000, 'status': 'OPEN', 'bike_stands': 50, 'banking': 
True, 'available_bikes': 6, 'name': '31705 - CHAMPEAUX (BAGNOLET)', 'bonus': Tru
e, 'number': 31705, 'contract_name': 'Paris', 'address': 'RUE DES CHAMPEAUX (PRE
S DE LA GARE ROUTIERE) - 93170 BAGNOLET', 'position': {'lng': 2.416170724425901,
 'lat': 48.8645278209514}, 'available_bike_stands': 43}, {'last_update': 1497175
566000, 'status': 'OPEN', 'bike_stands': 33, 'banking': True, 'available_bikes':
 17, 'name': '10042 - POISSONNIÈRE - ENGHIEN', 'bonus': False, 'number': 10042, 
'contract_name': 'Paris', 'address': "52 RUE D'ENGHIEN / ANGLE RUE DU FAUBOURG P
OISSONIERE - 75010 PARIS", 'position': {'lng': 2.348395236282807, 'lat': 48.8724
2006305313}, 'available_bike_stands': 15}, ...]
```

Comment: lR0 is the length of R_0, just fixed lR0

Comment: i re adjusted everything

Comment: just edited the post

Comment: Lt0[k] contains the value of bikes in the station number k at a time t and Lt1[k] the value of bikes at a time t+T

Comment: Now, you have a valid question.

Comment: Thanks sorry about all that

Answer (score 0):

You could try something along the line of this:

```
from collections import defaultdict
import requests
import time


def get_json():
    R_0_json = requests.get('https://api.jcdecaux.com/vls/v1/stations?contract=Paris&apiKey=an apikey')
    return R_0_json.json()


# Initialize available_bikes_before
R_0 = get_json()
available_bikes_before = {station['name']: station['available_bikes'] for station in R_0}

time.sleep(150)

I_0 = defaultdict(int) 
for c in xrange(288):
    R_0 = get_json()
    for station in R_0:
        available_bikes_now = station['available_bikes']
        I_0[station['name']] += abs(available_bikes_now -
                                    available_bikes_before[station['name']])
        available_bikes_before[station['name']] = available_bikes_now

    time.sleep(150)

print(I_0)
```

If you are just interested in the values and not the mapping to the stations, then you could use `I_0.values()` to access the values. However, they will not be ordered in a predictable way. If the order matters, you can modify the code above like this:

```
I_0 = [0] * len(R_0)
for c in xrange(288):
    R_0 = get_json()
    for k, station in enumerate(R_0):
        available_bikes_now = station['available_bikes']
        I_0[k] += abs(available_bikes_now - available_bikes_before[station['name']])
        available_bikes_before[station['name']] = available_bikes_now

    time.sleep(150)

print(I_0)
```

Note the changes for I_0: it is now a list and we use an index k to populate its values. The rest of the code stays the same.

Comment: Hi, the result is defaultdict(<class 'int'>, {'18018 - CARPEAUX': 2, '12009- DIDEROT': 2, '21003 # - JAURES 1 (BOULOGNE-BILLANCOURT)': 7, '11041 - SAINT AMBROISE': 6, '15006 - CHE.... )How do you convert I_0 to a list of the variations, without all the names ? just a list with the numbers which are the variations ?

Comment: I added another version of the solution that outputs a list instead of a dictionary.